# Accessing store from Quasar boot file

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, quasar-framework

I am using Quasar and I have in a boot file (basically same as main.js):

```js
Vue.use(VueCurrencyFilter, {
  symbol: '$',
  thousandsSeparator: '.',
  fractionCount: 2,
  fractionSeparator: ',',
  symbolPosition: 'front',
  symbolSpacing: true
})
```

I can do in my component:

```
{{purchaseOrderTotal | currency(currentLocation.currency)}}
```

`currentLocation` is a state in my store called with mapState.

`currentLocation.currency` is the currency for `symbol` option.

This works but means I have to pass the param in every component.

Is there any way to call `currentLocation.currency` in the js file to be used as default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forgot about anatomy of boot files in Quasar:

```
import VueCurrencyFilter from 'vue-currency-filter'

export default ({ Vue, store }) => {

    Vue.use(VueCurrencyFilter,
      .......
};
```

store needed to be exported instead of imported.

Answer (score 2):

You can import the Vuex store into any module:

```js
import store from '@/store';
```

And use it in that file the same as though you were using it in a component:

```js
let currency = store.state.currentLocation.currency;
```

This is the same `this.$store` object that's accessible through the components.

Comment: Quasar provides the store as parameter in the boot callback so no need to import it.
https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/boot-files#Anatomy-of-a-boot-file

Comment: @TonyO'Hagan Doesn't Catmal's answer use that method?  This is a general answer that will work in any environment.

Comment: If anybody is going to try this In Quasar 2, this won't work. You'll get "Module not found: Can't resolve imported dependency "@/store"".

Answer (score 0):

In Quasar 2 an alternative is to create a new boot file: quasar new boot ***file***

In the created file ../boot/***file***.(js|ts) we define the variable: ***mystore*** (Or also ***myrouter*** if we want to use *store* and *router* in your functions)

And we initialize them from the "export default":

```
import { boot } from 'quasar/wrappers'

let myrouter = null;
let mystore = null;


/**
 * @param {Array} value 
 */
const redirectFromLogin = (value) => {
  
  if (value.length > 1) {
    //set routing
    myrouter.push("/multiple");
  } else {
    //set routing
    myrouter.push("/single");
  }
}


/**
 * @param {Array} userdata 
 */
const saveUser = (userdata) => {
  // Save user info in Store
  mystore.commit("userstore/setUser", userdata);

}


// "async" is optional;
// more info on params: https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli/boot-files

export default boot(async ({ app, router, store }) => {
  myrouter = router;
  mystore = store

})
export { saveUser, redirectFromLogin }
```